# Keeping a private python package installed and up to date

Tags: python, git, pip

Question regarding installation of a Python-package from a private git-repository.

I have an `init.py`-file that is run whenever a user logs in to my service. This script is responsible for installing required packages, amongst others a python-package (with `setup.py`) from a private repository.

#### I am looking for ways to:

1. Install the latest version of the package if not currently installed.
2. Update the package, if the current installed version is not the latest.
3. Perform no action, if the latest version of the package already is installed.

#### I have tried the following:

1. Using `pip install --upgrade git+ssh://...`, however this always performs a clean install of the package.
2. Using `pip install git+ssh://...`, however this will not update the package if the current version is not the latest.

#### I am currently looking into ways of doing this manually by:

1. Git cloning the repository if it does not exist locally; then,
2. Call `python setup.py develop` to install the package in develop mode; then finally,
3. Do a `git stash; git pull` to discard any changes to working directory, and automatically pull latest changes.

However, I feel this approach is prone to users messing up.

I'd love if someone could provide some insight into this issue.
Thanks in advance!